# My display doesn't work but the touch-screen does

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, screen

My display doesn't work, but the touch-screen portion still works.

Will I need a new digitizer or will just a screen replacement do?

Comment: How do you know that the touch-screen still works? Have you connected the device to a TV or something to know that touches are still being detected? I'm just curious (and it may help determine if you need to replace one or more parts).

Comment: More to the point, though: most devices nowadays have the digitizer, lcd, and glass all fused into a single piece. Thus, it is impractical to try replacing only one part.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger I know because I can still unlock it (since I've memorized where it was) and hear the feedback. Same with moving around icons etc. Was just asking because the digitizers can get pricey. Thanks for the info!